# Removing None Option in PickList visualforce apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

i have created an object with name PS_Detail__c .in this custom object i created a custom field .in this picklist i defined two values Dollar ,Unit[image: here is screen shot for field description.].
when i go to P/S Detail Tab for creating a new PS_Detail__c object then i get None also as a value in picklist field .i want only Dollar and Unit as Picklist values .some one please help how to remove this None from Picklist !!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, you cannot make this picklist required at the object level. However, making this field required on the **page layout** will remove the -None- option from the available options.

To do this, edit the page layout on your object and select the wrench icon next to your field:
[image: select the wrench icon next to your field]

Then, you should be able to check the "Required" box in the dialogue box that pops up:
[image: check the "Required" box in the dialogue box that pops up]

Comment: there is no option for making it required the picklist field try it your self r u able to see required option ??

Comment: Please see the screenshots I have added in my response. You won't be able to make the field required at the object level, so you'll need to make it required on the page layout itself.