# Salesforce how to remove -none- from custom piclkist?

Tags: salesforce

I have Custom Picklist on Lead object. lead object has got three record type and all record type having default values i.e -auswahl- specified in it works fine and shows defualt value. from field also i have made -auswahl-  fild as default but the problem is that still it shows  -None- in picklist i want to remove -none- from picklist.

picklist shows option like below.

-auswahl- (default)
-none-
secondvalue
thirdvalue

(Making picklist required from page layout doesn't solve problem.)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109797/removing-none-option-in-picklist-visualforce-apex

Answer (score 0):

Setup -> Customize -> Leads -> Fields -> [your Custom Picklist name].
The very bottom section named 'Picklist Values'. Press 'edit' action in front of value which you want to make default. Check 'Defaul' checkbox. Save.

Comment: Hi Chiz,
Thanks, i have tried that way also but still because of some reason -None- is displaying there.

Comment: Oh, why you just didn't remove '-none-' value from possible values for your picklist?

Comment: One more question. Do you use standard edit page or custom Visualforce?

Comment: i dont see -none- while editing picklist. and I am using Custom Visualforce page and displaying.

Comment: Then you need to look into your controller - you may set '-none-' there.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest one tweak if removing '--None--' is very necessary. Although I will not recommend.

1. Remove the field from Page Layout
2. Create one field in Lead object
3. Create a inline VF page for this particular field
4. Onload of inline VF page you can run a javascript for removing '--None--' node from select option list
5. Also you will have to couple the value inserted/edited by User in the vf page with the field created in step 2 using onchange event of picklist ie. again using javascript
6. Override save button in the standard pae and set the value of picklist using field created in step 2

I have not tried the solution but pretty sure this will work. Let me know if you need this workaround. I will post the code after trying at my end.